# Wordpress get public user data

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, user-profile

I am trying to get all the info about the user when opening the public page.

I use this function to get the current user data:

```
<?php global $current_user;
  wp_get_current_user();
   echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
   echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
 ?>
```

However i need the information not about the logged in user but about the user i am visiting the page.
How can i get the info of the user in his public page and store it in a variable?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean about "the user i am visiting the page" ?  Are you asking about having details on a non-logged in user?

Comment: yes. about the profile of another user and the one is logged in. E.g.when you visit the page of a person in facebook

Comment: Do you mean like their `author` page?

Comment: yes exactly i mean this

Answer (score 0):

So you either need to put this in your `archive.php` template or `author.php` template.

See the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) for more details on that.

```php
// Check that it's an author archive with is_author()      
if (is_author()){
    $user = get_queried_object(); // If user will return object WP_User
    echo 'Username: ' . $user->user_login . "\n";
    echo 'User display name: ' . $user->display_name . "\n"; 
}
```